installing ventless all in one washer/dryer combo
I own an inlaw suite that doesn't have connections for a washer. The bathroom has a macerating toilet system that can run toilet, shower, kitchen sink and a washing machine. What plumbing do I tap into exactly to run the hot and cold water lines for the washing machine?

i have a dual shut off valve under kitchen sink, thats being used by the bathroom & kitchen sink, that is the closest lines i got to the washing machine

Welcome. Please take the [tour]. I think your question needs more information.

Basically, wherever you have convenient access to hot and cold water, usually the closest point to where the machine will be, preferably where you can keep the hoses behind the machine where they won't be stepped on/tripped over. I presume you have already figured out how the machine will drain, remembering that the drain hose has to go high enough to prevent syphoning water out of the machine.

You report in a comment that there is a Tee-d set of water supply pipes under the kitchen sink, feeding the bathroom sink as well. Tap there under the kitchen sink with another set of Tee's.
It is possible there are flexible screw-on hoses between the in-wall water supply pipes/valves for the sink and the faucet. If so, there are T's that screw onto the valves to get another set of hoses attached to the sink supply. If not, you'd have to see what is there and consult with a hardware store to find a way to get the extra T connections installed.
Then convert whatever T devices you got to whatever form of threads your washing machine's hoses use, with adapters from the hardware store. Attach your washing machine hoses to the adapters.
Attach the washing machine drain hose per instructions to the macerating toilet, and get to washing clothes!

thank you for your help, i will see about doing just that.
